# Sending woocommerce data to page from php to be used as javascript safe?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, security, woocommerce

Im grabbing woocommerce user data in php and use javascript to add that data to an html input element. The buyer gets an email after woocommerce checkout. Inside the email is a link containing the order ID.

that id is passed in the URL like such: `www.mypage.com/some_page/?id=222`. Then i use php to get user email and name from the wc_order object.

The code works nicely but I'm not sure if the following procedure is a security threat. Any insight appreciated.

PHP inserted via WPCode shortcode in wordpress page

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $order = wc_get_order( $id );
    $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $billing_first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $billing_last_name = $order->get_billing_last_name();
    echo "<script>var wc_user = '" . $billing_first_name . " " . $billing_last_name . "'; var wc_email = '" . $billing_email."';</script>";
}
```

Javascript via WPCode shortcode in wordpress page

```
nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
emailInput = document.getElementById("email");   
nameInput.value=wc_user;
emailInput.value=wc_email;
nameInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
emailInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
```